# agent.runWithDocumentContext(document) retrieve document "body" field

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

In one of our XPages application we use the class
 `agent.runWithDocumentContext(document)`

This we must use instead of bind the XPage directly to the Notes Document, because the user have no direct access to the database which inherit the Document source.
So after the agent was run we get the needed field information from the returned document context and set this values to controls in our XPages dialog.
All things fine, but the source document have also a Body field in the Lotus Notes Richtext format or Mime.

Now the concern we have are:
1. How do we pull and display the document `body` field to the richtext manually from document context? 
2. How do we pull all the attachment from the document context?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to copy the document wholesale into the response?

```
call secretDoc.copyAllItems(contextDoc)
```

that should give you access to all you need. You also could consider a "working database" where users have access and your agent copies the document there, you use it and then an agent picks the changes you need to write back and deletes it from the working database.
Just recreate the database from time to time.

Comment: Hi stwissel, Thanks for the suggested solution. however we currently used the copyAllItems method. the problem we encountering is how to  display the document "body" field as mime and display it correctly on the richtext (chkeditor) on the xpages control, and so w/ the attachment.

Comment: Notes Client Rich Text cannot easily be displayed on the web, whether XPages or anything else. The way round displaying rich text as MIME is to set the property on the Notes Rich Text field to store contents as MIME. But you'll probably still have problems if you're editing it then in XPages. Notes Client to web round tripping of rich text is notoriously difficult. As far as I know there's no way to show attachments inline in an editor, CKEditor, Dojo or other. If you can find a web editor that provides that functionality, you may be able to plug it in, but I don't know anyone who has done it.

Comment: In theory you can show inline.... but the roundtrip editing is something you want to avoid. For the "inline" show you would need to customize CKEditor to insert an image (for the file type) and a link in one go (after uploading the file). Then you need to postprocess and also remove the attachments that are no longer linked to -- messsy business, but that's how HTML works